# ParseExact inverse my day and month

Tags: c#, datetime

my code below throw an exception as invalid date time. the error occur after i publish it to my server. working find at my developing PC

```
string str = "27-07-2015 6:15 pm";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd-MM-yyyy h:mm tt", null).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt"));
```

it takes '27' as month and '7' as day.

what i did to solve the problem:

- i already update the datetime format on that server to dd-MM-yyyy
- i double checked the capital and small letter of the date time format.
- change the 'null' to 'CultureInfo.InvariantCulture'
- change 'pm' to 'PM', 'tt' to 'TT'
- read through all the resources i could find on google and stackoverflow, nothing's help.

am i missing something here? i know i did... :(

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Why are you parsing a string to a `DateTime`, converting it back to a string, and then converting that to a `DateTime`?

Comment: DateTime struct does not hold display format information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Rawling correctly noted, you're parsing the datetime twice: first, using your custom formatting, and second, using the system's default formatting.

This is silly - you already have the `DateTime` from the `ParseExact` method:

```
string str = "27-07-2015 6:15 pm";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd-MM-yyyy h:mm tt", null);
```

That's it, you're done. No need to convert to string again, and parse that once more (and even worse, using the same custom formatting to do the `ToString`, so the subsequent `Convert.ToDateTime` is *bound* to fail anywhere that's not the default datetime formatting).

Comment: the reason i use `Convert.ToDateTime` because sometime i want to convert it to another format, such as 'dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm' and so on..

Comment: @user3431239 That is an issue of presentation, not of the data. When you want to display the date time (or, say, store it in a file), it's just fine to use `ToString` (local or invariant, depending on the exact scenario). But the internal representation should still be the same `DateTime` - the `string` is a just a representation of the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities;

Let's analyze your `DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd-MM-yyyy h:mm tt", null)` part first. This will be parsed your `27-07-2015 6:15 pm` string successfully **if**;

- Your `CurrentCulture`'s [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `:` and
- Your `CurrentCulture`'s [`PMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.pmdesignator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `PM` (*not empty string*)

If both are okey, you have successfully parsed a `DateTime`.

After that, you generate it's *textual* representation with `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt` format. And that's still depends on your `CurrentCulture`, your result *might* have `PM` or not. For both case, there is no guaranteed to parse your string with `Convert.ToDateTime` method because it will be parsed your string only **if** it is a [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) of your `CurrentCulture`.

On the other side, what you do doesn't make sense to me. You parse your string first, then you generate string representation of it, then you try to parse this string *again*. Doesn't make sense, right?

I strongly suspect you just need;

```
string str = "27-07-2015 6:15 pm";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd-MM-yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```